# WordPress: Query Ordering by Parent Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a number of custom WordPress queries in my theme. They all work great, except rather than sorting them by the post titles, I need to sort them alphabetically by their *parent's* post titles.

There doesn't seem to be a default argument for 'orderby' to accomplish this, but I know there must still be a way to get it done.

All of the posts returned from my query are child posts, so they all have a parent.

Just for reference, here's an example query showing my format. Maybe I have a CPT 'books' and each book has posts for chapter 1, chapter 2, etc. If I want to list all of the 'Chapter 1' posts for every book, sorted alphabetically by book title:

```
// List Chapter 1 for all Books

function query_ch1() {
  global $post;
  $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'book',
    'name'           => 'chapter-1',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'title'
  );
  $query_ch1 = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query_ch1->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_ch1->have_posts() ) {
        $query_ch1->the_post();
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
        echo get_the_title();
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
}
```

However this, of course, would list all chapter 1 posts by their own post titles rather than their parents'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do it (as far as efficiency, etc.), but after a lot of experimenting this is how I ended up getting the desired effect.

Using the example in my original post, it would be:

```
// List Chapter 1 for all Books

function query_ch1() {
  global $post;
  $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'book',
    'post_parent'    => '0',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'title'
  );
  $query_ch1 = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $query_ch1->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_ch1->have_posts() ) {
      $query_ch1->the_post();
      $children = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'name' => 'chapter-1' ) );
      foreach ( $children as $post ) {
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
        echo get_the_title();
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
}
```

So after reading Melvin Koopmans' suggestion I changed my query to pull top-level pages rather than the children so that they'd be sorted correctly, and then nested get_children() and foreach($children as $post) to do the stuff.

Comment: Yeah thats a great solution. Good job

Answer (score 1):

This is something you could try:

- Query all posts with something like `get_posts($args)`.
- Start building an array: `$parents = [];`
- Loop over all posts and get the title of their with something like `$parentTitle = get_the_title($post->post_parent)`.
- Add the posts to their parents key in `$parents`. Something like: `$parents[$parentTitle][] = $post;`
- Now I think you should be able to do `ksort($parents);` to sort the `$parents` array based on the keys.

Now you can loop over the `$parents` and then loop over its `posts`:

```
foreach ($parents as $posts) {

    foreach ($posts as $post)
        // Do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up doing something a bit different with inspiration from how you approached this.